# Adding and counting every word in a string to a linked list

Tags: c#, text-parsing, string-parsing, singly-linked-list

I'll start off by saying I haven't quite wrapped my head around OOP.

I need a routine that iterates through each word in a string, checks to see if it is in my linked list and either adds it as a node if it is not or increases the count of the existing node if it is in the list.

Here is what I have:

```
private void CountWords(string cleanString)
        {
            WordNode nextNode, prevNode;
            WordNode addNode;
            foreach (string stringWord in cleanString.Split(' '))
            {
                if (head == null)
                {
                    // No items in list, add to the beginning
                    addNode = new WordNode(stringWord);
                    head = addNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (String.Compare(stringWord, head.Word) < 0)
                    {
                        // If stringWord belongs at the beginning of the list, put it there
                        addNode = new WordNode(stringWord);
                        addNode.NextWord = head;
                        head = addNode;
                    }
                    else if (String.Compare(stringWord, head.Word) == 0)
                    {
                        // If stringWord is equal to head.Word, increase count
                        addNode.Count += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prevNode = head;
                        nextNode = head.NextWord;
                        // If it doesn't belong at the beginning, cycle through the list until you find where it does belong
                        while ((nextNode != null) && (String.Compare(nextNode.Word, addNode.Word) < 0))
                        {
                            prevNode = nextNode;
                            nextNode = nextNode.NextWord;
                        }
                        if (nextNode == null)
                        {
                            prevNode.NextWord = addNode;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prevNode.NextWord = addNode;
                            addNode.NextWord = nextNode;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Before this, I was attempting the **addNode = new WordNode(stringWord);** at the beginning of each iteration through the "for each word in string" loop,  but that would re define the class and reset count to 1.  Now, currently, I can't increase the count, because **addNode.Count += 1;** is undefined.  I was hoping I could check to see if stringWord was in the linked list, and if so, increment stringWord.count by one, but that throws an error.

Looking at this now, I'm thinking the **addNode.Count += 1;** belongs in the while loop a few lines below it...

Here is my WordNode class:

```
class WordNode
    {
        // constants

        // variables
        private string data;            // this is our only data, so also key
        private int count;
        private WordNode next;          // this is reference to next Node

        // constructors
        public WordNode(string newValue)
        {
            Word = newValue;
            count = 1;
            NextWord = null;
        }

        // methods
        public string Word
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
            set
            {
                count = value;
            }
        }

        public WordNode NextWord
        {
            get
            {
                return next;
            }
            set
            {
                next = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void CountWords(string cleanString)
{
    foreach (string stringWord in cleanString.Split(' '))
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new WordNode(stringWord);
        }
        else
        {
            var last = (WordNode)null;
            var current = head;
            do
            {
                if (current.Word == stringWord)
                {
                    break;
                }
                last = current;
                current = current.NextWord;
            } while (current != null);
            if (current != null)
            {
                current.Count++;
            }
            else
            {
                last.NextWord = new WordNode(stringWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And alternative is to use linq:

```
var query =
    cleanString
        .Split(' ')
        .ToLookup(x => x)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Word = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count(),
        });
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does the trick, though they're not in alphabetical order (but I didn't specify that in my original post).

Comment: It's easy to add a sort method to my linq approach.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dictionary<string,int> myDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(string str in listOfWords)
{
   myDict.add(str,0);
}

foreach(string x in cleanText.split(' '))
{
if(myDict.ContainsKey(x))
   myDict[x]+=1;
}
```

After running through the foreach myDict will contain counts for each word in the "bag of words."

**Edit**

```
if(myDict == null)
   myDict = new Dictionary<string,int>(); //assuming running tally at higher scope.


foreach(string x in cleanText.split(' '))
{
if(myDict.ContainsKey(x))
   myDict[x]+=1;
else
   myDict.add(x,1);
}
```

Comment: This only works if `listOfWords` already contains all the words produced, which you don't have the code to ensure happens. Why not just add new words' count of 1 as you go?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to practice making a linked list so this might not be helpful, but a much simpler solution is to use Key/Value pair like a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> Words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string wordsList = "a list of words for testing a list of words for testing";
foreach (string word in wordsList.Split(' '))
{
   if (Words[word] == null)
      Words[word] = 1;
   else
      Words[word] += 1;
}
System.Console.WriteLine("testing: {0}", Words["testing"]); //result- testing: 2
```

The result of indexing the Words dictionary by the string will return the number of words.

Comment: That would throw a `KeyNotFoundException` on the first iteration. Are you thinking of the way `Hashtable` worked? If you'd defined an `int count` previously then you could have assigned reliably with `Words[word] = Words.TryGetValue(word, out count) ? count + 1 : 1`. (Or even just call it and add one, since it'd set `count` to `default(int)` which is `0` if nothing was found, though there's something a tad kludgy feeling about that).